# appending text to all columns at once in sas

Tags: sas

I have a tables which have columns from col1 to col10.
I would like to append a string such as italy_col1 to italy_col10.
how can I achieve this without a macro.
Since i am joining multiple table i want to append a text "Italy" for all column in table 1 and "USA" in table 2. I tried below example it doesnt suit my requirement
https://support.sas.com/kb/48/674.html

```
cats function appends all the values in the column of the tables. Any suggestions?
```

Comment: Please clarify. Are you trying to RENAME variables? Or modify the data stored in the variables?

Comment: Renaming variable names.

Comment: Please post a simple example of input datasets and what output you want. I assume you want to rename them so you can combine the datasets. Show how you want to combine the datasets and the result you want for your simple example inputs.  Also is there a pattern that can be used to map the name of the source dataset to the prefix you want to add when renaming the variables in that dataset?

Comment: The linked code does not need a macro, but it does need dynamic code. You can get some simple dynamic code by using queries like those in the posted text to generate macro variable(s) that you can then use later to complete your program. Show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate macro variables and then use those in your code.

First get lists of variables to rename from TABLE1 and TABLE2.

```
proc sql noprint;
select catx('=',name,cats('Italy_',name) into :rename1 separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns 
  where libname="WORK" and memname="TABLE1" and upcase(name) ne 'ID'
;
select catx('=',name,cats('USA_',name) into :rename2 separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns 
  where libname="WORK" and memname="TABLE2" and upcase(name) ne 'ID'
;
quit;
```

Then use the list of rename pairs in your code that merges the datasets.

```
data want;
   merge table1(rename=(&rename1)) table2(rename=(&rename2));
   by id;
run;
```

Note this will only work when the number of variables to rename is small enough to fit into a single macro variable.  If the list is longer just use another method, such as a data step, to generate the same code.

Also watch out for variable names that are too long.  SAS has a limit of 32 bytes for variable names so adding 4 or 7 extra characters might result in names that are too long.  You might just truncate to 32 characters , but then you risk forming duplicate names.